# My CMS is stripping out the ? at the end of a URL when I try to save the link... is there a way to make it stick?

Tags: url, content-management-system

Basically we're trying to change all of the book now or book online reservations on our website. For example, on our whale watching page, the new reservation link needs to look like this:

```
https://reservations.whales.com/res(L10!group=a)?
```

Here's where I'm entering the URL in the back end of my website: http://oi62.tinypic.com/j61ysg.jpg

The problem is when I enter the URL with the question mark at the end in our CMS, and I click save, it strips out the ? at the end, which messes up the query I'm trying to get it to do. Is there a way I could - just as an example - enclose the ? in some other characters so that the ? isn't at the end? (Maybe my CMS only has a problem with it being at the end?) I'm open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by adding a / to the end of the URL.